# What is the difference between android:theme and android:background?

Tags: android

To add the gradient background somebody suggest to use `android:background` and others say `android:theme`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android: background` will set the background in your current view/layout.

`Themes` on Android allow you to separate the details of your app design from the UI structure and behavior, similar to stylesheets in web design.

A theme is more of a collective thing which has its impact on overall UI of your screen. Like the color of the action bar, the color of the line in your edit text etc.

You can read more details about themes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html).